# Rails Query: Filter by properties in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm seeking a clear Rails 4 example on how to filter records based on data associated to them via another table.

Suppose I have a Users model and a Comments model. A User `has_many` comments, and a Comment `belongs_to` a user. A comment also has a `score` column in its table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

```
 Users
| id  | name    | email               |
|-----|---------|---------------------|
| 1   | "Alice" | "alice@example.com" |
| 2   | "Bob"   | "bob@example.com"   |
| ...                                 |
```

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end 

 Comments
| id  | score | content          | user_id |
|-----|-------|------------------|---------|
| 1   | 0     | "lol"            | 2       |
| 2   | 2     | "more like love" | 3       |
| ...                                      |
```

How would I obtain all users that have made a comment with the content "k" that has a score > 0? Note that what I want to return is the Users, not the Comments.

---

Also, consider a more complex example, where a User `has_many` comments and likes, Comments `belong_to` a user, and a Comment `has_many` Likes. Likes `belong_to` a User and `belong_to` a Comment. Note that `score` is no longer a factor in this example.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes
end
```

```
 Users
| id  | name    | email               |
|-----|---------|---------------------|
| 1   | "Alice" | "alice@example.com" |
| 2   | "Bob"   | "bob@example.com"   |
| ...                                 |
```

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
end
```

```
 Comments
| id  | content          | user_id |
|-----|------------------|---------|
| 1   | "lol"            | 2       |
| 2   | "more like love" | 3       |
| ...                              |
```

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

```
 Likes
| id  | user_id | comment_id |
|-----|---------|------------|
| 1   | 1       | 2          |
| 2   | 4       | 3          |
| ...                        |
```

In this second example, how would I find all the Users who have ever had one of their comments liked by the User named 'Fonzie'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your first question. You need to create a new tabular structure that references the association between the users and comments table.

This can be achieved by `User.joins(:comments)`. Now you have a table that has all the users with their associated comments. To apply your filters you can simply do:

`User.joins(:comments)
  .where("comments.content = ? AND comments.score > ?", 'some_content', 0)`

If you are not familiar with the above, I suggest you read the [rails guidelines on queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) - search for 'Joining Tables'

Since the second example is a bit more complex, I'd suggest that you familiarise yourself first with the guides above.